mknod() not creating an S_IFIFO pipe, WSL2
I'm trying to create an S_IFIFO pipe with mknod(file, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0). It's failing with errno 95 (Operation not supported)
Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main() {
    char file[] = "pipe.txt";
    int state;
    umask(0);
    state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0);
    printf("errno: %d\n", errno);
    perror("Error");
    printf("state %d\n", state);
    return 0;
}

Output:
errno: 95
Error: Operation not supported
state -1

Note: If I pass 0 instead of S_IFIFO | 0600, than this creates the file, but with -r-xr-xr-x permissions.

Unrelated, but you shouldn't really check errno unless the last function actually failed. If the function didn't return with an error, the value of errno is unspecified.You also need to use it immediately (or save a copy of it). If you call any other function in between, the value becomes unspecified again.

I don't use WSL, but is this mapped to a Windows filesystem by any chance? There are obvious things that all filesystems can do, like files and directories, but at the end of the day, NTFS is a Windows filesystem, not a Unix-ish one. It does some things differently (like permissions), it offers features that Unix filesystems don't have, and it lacks features that Unix filesystems do have. I wouldn't be surprised if that particular feature you were trying to use has no obvious equivalent on NTFS, so the interface layer simply returned a "not supported" instead of trying to somehow emulate it.

I copied your code and ran it no problem under wsl2. Links that may help: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3962  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

I don't know how to upvote comments, but Christian Stieber was right. From wsl2, I had a symlink to Windows folder where I was building and running the program. It worked as soon as I moved the out file to "proper linux space"
